# Windows 7 VL question

Tags: windows

I hope this is an ok question for SF.

We are purchasing some Win7 copies and supposedly they can only sell upgrade licenses in VL, or OEM licenses individually, which would mean I get the media and a sticker for each license.

We previously had 25 copies of Vista, so we are purchasing 25 Upgrade Licenses for Win7 in VL format.

Going forward, we need to purchase 25 more copies which would be full installs (as we did not previously own a total of 50 licenses, only 25) So they are telling me I would need to purchase 25 OEM licenses. I don't want to constantly track 25 stickers. I'd much rather have 1 VL key. Is my rep confused? Can I actually just purchase 25 more Upgrades of Win7 in VL format and that will be ok? He tells me they are the same cost, 1 lic of VL is $144, and 1 lic of OEM (includes media and 1 lic sticker) is $144.

I think my rep is confused. But I am not sure. I am hoping to run into a MS expert on here.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't "Software Licensing Fault". The consensus that the Server Fault community often comes to on these questions is "Talk to a licensing specialist from the manufacturer."

Answer (score 2):

Evan is right... call Microsoft directly and get a definitive answer.  From the [Microsoft Volume Licensing FAQ](http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/resources/faq.mspx):

> "You can call (800) 426-9400, Monday
>   through Friday, 6:00 A.M.–5:30 P.M.
>   Pacific Time to speak directly to a
>   Microsoft licensing specialist.
>   Worldwide customers can see [Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/worldwide.aspx)
>   [licensing sites worldwide](http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/worldwide.aspx) to find
>   contact information in their
>   locations."